# Parenting and children

Tags: dharma

What are the rules of parenting or parenting quotes according to scriptures?What does the scriptures say about the qualities of a good parent/guardian and a bad parent/guardian?What should a child do who has terribly abusive parent?Can the child decide to seperate from them,is there an instance where such a thing happened?What are the quotes regarding dharma of protection and treatment of children ?